# Android Wallpaper is real or virtual ? Why live wallpaper is not displayed in sample home screen app?

Tags: android, homescreen

I am creating an HOME screen application for my android device. I am creating this app with the help of Android sample Home application. I found one thing in home sample app, if we set wallpaper it is calling  `android.content.ContextWrapper.setWallpaper(InputStream data);` to set wallpaper.

In this app a BroadcastReceiver with action `Intent.ACTION_WALLPAPER_CHANGED` already registered to catch the changes to wallpaper, then in OnReceive() method, using below code

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ClippedDrawable(getWallpaper()));
```

to set background to application window.

So if we are using same app as our home screen, we thought the wallpaper is really set as background in window, but its not true.

If i set any live wallpaper, its not displaying as background in home screen app. The previous wallpaper only displaying in window. If i use default home screen app its displaying the live wallpaper.

Finally i want to know one thing, why live wallpaper is not displayed in app window when i am using sample home screen app ?

If anybody know about this, please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set live wallpapers by code, this can only be done with static wallpapers.